# How to get page's content info before replication(DELETE)?

Tags: osgi, aem, sling

In CQ5, I need to collect some info from page properties and child nodes properties befor replication(delete) occurs

If i implement [EventHandler](https://osgi.org/javadoc/r4v42/org/osgi/service/event/EventHandler.html):

```
@Component(immediate = true)
@Service
@Property(name = EventConstants.EVENT_TOPIC, value = ReplicationAction.EVENT_TOPIC)
public class RedisVideoUpdaterService implements EventHandler {
..................

    public void handleEvent(Event event) {            

    ReplicationAction action = ReplicationAction.fromEvent(event);
    ReplicationActionType actionType = action.getType();

    if (actionType.equals(ReplicationActionType.DELETE)) {
        //process data collecting
    }

...............
```

After `handelEvent` triggered there page is already deleted.

If i implement [Preprocessor](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/javadoc/com/day/cq/replication/Preprocessor.html)

```
@Component(immediate = true)
@Service
public class RedisVideoUpdaterService implements Preprocessor{
..................

   public void preprocess(ReplicationAction action, ReplicationOptions replicationOptions) throws ReplicationException {         

    ReplicationActionType actionType = action.getType();

    if (actionType.equals(ReplicationActionType.DELETE)) {
        //process data collecting
    }

...............
```

`preprocess` method is not triggered at all on delete action.

Both cases are OK for actiovation/deactivation.

How can I process page before it have been deleted?

Comment: I have done something of this sort and the preprocessor implementation should work. are you using a custom replicator? you may want to debug line by line to see whats happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I noticed. `Preppocessor` triggered on delete only for activated pages. This behaviour is ok for me.